# How to solve "session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent"

Tags: php, yii, sessionid, byte-order-mark

I have moved a Yii app to another shared host. As the app was running ...index.php?r=site/login with login credentials, I got the warning:

```
session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent
```

the `actionLogin`''s code:

```
public function actionLogin($name = null )
{
    $model=new LoginForm;
    if ($name) $model->username = $name;
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if (headers_sent($filename, $linenum))
               {
            echo "Headers have been sent in {$filename} line number is {$linenum}\n"
            exit;
        }

        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

The docs and forums have said that there may be a problem with the BOM. Yet in my Notepad++ all files are saved as **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Should I do the special check of the files? Which ones? Or might there be another cause of the error?

I've added `headers_sent($filename, $linenum)` function (see in the code above) to trace the sent headers but with no result.

Comment: you have to further look into if you have read/write access to runtime and any cache file issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use

```
ob_start()
```

at the start of the file.

Comment: Thank you, chandresh_cool. i did it and it's helped, yet! Is the output preventing going to safely influence the rest of the code? I do not inclute ob_end().?

Comment: Hey Chandresh, thanks for your answer. I find it incomplete thought. Could you please explain why using `ob_start()` solves the issue?

Answer (score 7):

Generally this error arise when we send header after echoing or printing. If this error arise on a specific page then make sure that page is not echoing anything before calling to start_session().

Example of Unpredictable Error:

```
 <?php //a white-space before <?php also send for output and arise error
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

//your page content
```

Sometimes it dose not matter in your localhost computer, but matters in your remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I  had an empty line at the beginning of main.php in Yii Project, removing that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

From My experience its mostly an error of white spaces . Sometimes a space before
   the opening php tag  or some times a space in the end of your file 
after the closing  **?>**

```
 /* white spaces here*/   <?php

    //YOUR CODE 

 ?> /* white spaces here
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, also a Yii app, the same error was thrown upon logging in into the web app after deploying to a new infrastructure. I was able to compare the configuration files between the previous and new infrastructure and it turns out that I forgot to enable *output buffering* in **php.ini** on the php-fpm container.

[This old discussion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/88) about the error message on Yii's issues board on GitHub gave me the hint on what to look for in the config files.

Now in my **php.ini** I have this setting:

```
; Note: Output buffering can also be controlled via Output Buffering Control
;   functions.
; Possible Values:
;   On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution)
;   Off = Disabled
;   Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering = 4096
```

Hope it helps others too.

Comment: This did help me. Also a possible indication that you don't have any php.ini loaded at all, as the default output buffering setting is 0. In my case I was setting up an environment to test an old PHP app and I'd forgotten this step.

Answer (score 0):

Make user you not echoing anything in function where your are using $model->login()

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
ob_start();
```

if that won't work then try following

```
ob_start();
ob_clean();
```